# How to fix error Cannot find name 'object' in angular 2 cli ckeditor

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ckeditor, angular2-forms

I have insalled ng2-ckeditor using cli :

```
npm install ng2-ckeditor --save
```

Then Include CKEditor javascript files in my index file :

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Then imported module in module file:

```
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';
```

in imports "CKEditorModule"

and trying to use in html

It show error:

> ERROR in
>   /var/www/html/eventswebsite/frontendapp/node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/lib/ckeditor.component.d.ts
>   (43,26): Cannot find name 'object'.
>
> "ng2-ckeditor/lib/ckeditor.component.d.ts (43,26): Cannot find name
>   'object'."

its working if i change
ckeditorInit(config: object)

To

ckeditorInit(config: any)

in npm module ckeditor component file.

Comment: seems like error is in `ckeditor` , did you get any errors while installing? Also, if you have saved the module in your application why are you using a `cdn` for `js` ?

Comment: Which typescript version are you using? `object` is a keyword in TS2.2

Comment: Hello @BhavikPatel i have't got any error while installing. cdn i am just using for now when everthing will be working i will replace it with relative path.

Comment: HI @yurzui 
Typescript version is 2.2.1 which is i am using.
tsc -v
Version 2.2.1

Comment: This error just only show when i use ng serve for build but after that if i comment both lines import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor'; and imports "CKEditorModule" then build works ok but as i removed ckeditor so i will not work then again i remove comment then ckeditor also works but my issue is i have to do this again n again everytime when i use ng serve

Comment: its working if i change
ckeditorInit(config: object) {
to:
ckeditorInit(config: any) {

in npm module ckeditor component file.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this answer for those who are facing this error  "Cannot find name 'object'" irrespective of which component they are getting this error in. This is a tsc compiler version related issue. 'object' is keyword in TS2.2.

I am using VS 2017 Community. By default it shipped with tsc 1.5 ie. typescript compiler version 1.5. I tried updating it from Nuget and also installed "typescript for VS 2017" nothing helped, even though my computer had latest version of typescript, but VS typescript version was still 1.5.

Then I searched for Microsoft's latest update of VS 2017, fortunately for me notification of latest release was found on top bar of VS. After installing the latest update I got my typescript version on VS updated to 2.2. This resolved the issue and compilation errors were gone.

As a side note, you can find the version of typescript VS is using under menu "Help\About Microsoft Visual Studio", then on pop up screen scroll down a bit as shown in below image:[image: typescript version in visual studio 2017]