# Error while installing Bot Framework Emulator on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am unable to install microsoft emulator on ubuntu 16.04.

I downloaded `BotFramework-Emulator-3.5.29.zip` file from the portal, then extracted it and run `npm install` successfully (but got the following message):

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 7zip-bin-mac@^1.0.1(node_modules/7zip-bin/node_modules/7zip-bin-mac):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 7zip-bin-mac@1.0.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 7zip-bin-win@^2.1.0 (node_modules/7zip-bin/node_modules/7zip-bin-win):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 7zip-bin-win@2.1.0: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Then `gulp build-app` throws the following error:

```
[14:32:40] Using gulpfile /var/www/BotFramework-Emulator-3.5.29/gulpfile.js
[14:32:40] Starting 'clean'...
[14:32:40] Finished 'clean' after 23 ms
[14:32:40] Starting 'build-app'...
[14:32:40] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 2.1.5
[14:32:46] [tsc] > node_modules/botframework-directlinejs/built/directLine.d.ts(204,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'object'.
[14:32:46] Failed to compile TypeScript: Error: tsc command has exited with code:1

  events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: Failed to compile: tsc command has exited with code:1
```

Comment: What's your problem? Emulator, or MS Teams integration? Your title is not explicit

Comment: @NicolasR installing BotFramework-Emulator app in ubutu
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v3.5.29

Comment: ok I cleaned title, tags and content

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one strange thing: in `package.json` there is a dependency `"typescript": "2.2.2"`, but in your log it says `Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 2.1.5`. Isn't there a problem of TypeScript version?

Can you try to update Typescript to 2.2 and run everything again?

It seems that your error `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'object'.` is due to the fact that `object` is keyword in TS2.2 (see for example this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44143545/3136339) stating the same)

Comment: thanks it also worked, but there were other issues in building gulp app, i got the clue from you and resolved it, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

add the latest dependancies in package.json, may be some dependancies version changed after development
I changed all the version in package.json

```
"dependencies": {    "gulp-debug": "2.1.2",
"gulp-filter": "4.0.0",
"gulp-flatmap": "1.0.0",
"gulp-inject": "4.2.0",
"gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
"gulp-tsc": "1.2.6",
"gulp-util": "3.0.8",
"license-list": "0.1.3",
"object-assign": "4.1.0",
"tslib": "1.5.0",
"typescript": "2.2.2",
"vinyl": "2.0.1",
"vinyl-fs": "2.4.4"
},
```

then rebuild the gulp app

```
build gulp-app
```

then run the project with

```
npm start
```

this resolved me all issues and all works smooth